# UITableViewCellStyle.Value1 が適用されない

Tags: ios, swift

TableView の CellStyle について質問があります。
現在、xib 上に配置した View の上に配置した TableView を、UITableViewCellStyle.Value1 のスタイルで実現したいと考えておりますが、Value1が描画されず、Defaultのスタイルになってしまいます。

UITableViewCellStyle.Subtitle や UITableViewCellStyle.Value2 は正しくCellStyle が適用されるのですが、
何故か Value1 が適用されません。

下記のようなコードを記述しておりますが、不備はありますでしょうか。
提示コードに不足がありましたら、追加します。

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: "Cell")
    cell.textLabel?.text = "テスト"
    cell.detailTextLabel?.text = "詳細"

    return cell
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`detailTextLabel`の表示位置が、画面からはみ出しているのではありませんか？つまり、テーブルのサイズが、画面より横方向に大きすぎるのではありませんか？

質問とは離れますが……

[Table View Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone/AboutTableViewsiPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451)

Appleのガイドに従って、以下説明します。

`func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell`の実装は、次のように改善してください。

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "Cell" // セルのIDを定数identifierにする。
    var cell: UITableViewCell? // nilになることがあるので、Optionalで宣言
    // セルを再利用する。
    cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(identifier)
    if cell == nil { // 再利用するセルがなかったら（不足していたら）
        // セルを新規に作成する。
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Value1, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
    cell?.textLabel?.text = "テスト"
    cell?.detailTextLabel?.text = "詳細"

    return cell!
}
```

テーブルに表示される行の数が10行だとします。セルを再利用することを考えれば、セルの数は10+α個ですみます。テーブルの総行数を用意する必要はありません。そういう処理をしています。

Comment: 毎度ありがとうございます。お恥ずかしい話ですが、TableViewが画面からはみ出しておりました。。なかなかそこに気づけず・・・。
またセルの再利用について、ご教授いただきありがとうございます。
勉強不足につき、精進いたします。